# Force Python ast to emit lines no longer than length

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree, line-breaks

I've written a library that works at the ast level. Sometimes the generated output goes over the linter line length limit.

```
"foo_bar_can_haz_foo_bar_can_haz_foo_bar_can_haz_foo_bar_can_haz_foo_bar_can_haz_foo_bar_can_haz"
```

How do I generate this kind of code instead?

```
"foo_bar_can_haz_foo_bar_can_haz_foo_bar_can_haz_"
"foo_bar_can_haz_foo_bar_can_haz_foo_bar_can_haz"
```

(also happy with the `\` and parenthesised variants)

The only thing I can think of doing—retaining support for 3.6, 3.7, 3.8, 3.9, and 3.10a4—is to contribute to both [astor](https://github.com/berkerpeksag/astor) and the builtin [`ast.unparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.unparse)…

Comment: Use a separate Python code formatter after unparsing.

Comment: @gilch: I've tried `black` [incl. with `--experimental-string-processing`], `autoflake`, `autopep8` [incl. with `--aggressive`, `--aggressive` and `--max-line-length=119`]. None break all the strings until the linters pass (`black` gets closest).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding word-wrap support directly to my code-generation: https://github.com/SamuelMarks/doctrans/commit/6147b21e168b66623aa1be95cb38b1969daa5147